# Full expand the dropdown menu in mobile, but not in desktop on Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, drop-down-menu, navigationbar

I am new to wordpress and a would like to fully expand menu bar in the header on mobile version, but not in desktop. How can I do it in CSS? Here is the code I try, but not success:

```
.menu-item {
  display: none;
}

.open>.menu-item {
  display:block;
}
```

here is the html code:

```
<div id="primary-menu" class="menu"><ul>
<li class="page_item page-item-77 page_item_has_children current_page_item"> 
<a href="http://localhost/innospace/wordpress/?page_id=77">Facilities</a>
<ul class='children'>
<li class="page_item page-item-98"><a 
href="http://localhost/innospace/wordpress/?page_id=98">Printing</a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-181"><a 
href="http://localhost/innospace/wordpress/?page_id=181">Scanning</a> 
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="page_item page-item-14"><a 
href="http://localhost/innospace/wordpress/">welcome</a></li>
</ul></div>
```

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? Are you trying to apply different CSS rules to mobile and desktop? is the class `.open` dynamically added by JS/jQuery?

Comment: I want the menu bar expand automatically when it display on mobile

Answer (score 0):

you are close. use css media query like so

```
@media only screen and (max-width:600px) {
    .menu-item{
    display: block;
    }
  }
```

and have the default just be

```
.menu-item{
display: none;
}
```

play arround with the max width as it sets the css rules below it when the screen is below that width.